# Intersection of 4D Trajectory with 4D Polyeder (3D + time)

Tags: postgis, 3d, wgs84, trajectory

I have worldwide small polygons (lat/lon WGS84) for different heights (z-coordinate) for several timestamps (m). I want to store them in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database as 4D objects (2D polygons + height range + single timestamp).

I have several routes via multiple waypoints in the world with different start/end times. I know the time and height at every waypoint.

I want to get all of the polygons that are intersected by the route in four dimensions (lat/lon/z/m). Ideally with a buffer around each of the dimensions.

Is this possible with a single SQL `SELECT` with PostGIS? Are there other approaches?